# How to implement edge and collision detection on the x axis for two spheres?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, edge-detection

I'm trying to implement a edge and collision detection system on my simple two spheres(eyesballs) program.

Update

I have succeeded in implementing the edge detection properly, which can be found in the object.cpp

The collision detection is implemented but not working on contact, for some reason it works only after the objects pass each other a bit.

The objective was to have them make contact and then reset their positions to the starting position but as I said the position reset only kicks in after they pass each other.

I have posted the updated code along with extra I think may be necessary.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

object.h

```
class Object
{
public:

    bool edgeDetected();

    pos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    scale = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    rot = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
}
```

Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"


bool Object::edgeDetected()
{
    // edge detection x-axis
    if (pos.x < -2.126f)
    {
        pos.x = -2.126f;

        return true;
    }

    else if (pos.x > 2.126f)
    {
        pos.x = 2.126f;

        return true;
    }

    else
        return false;

}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include "Object.h"

void drawGUI();
bool collisionDetected( Object a, Object b);

Object* object1, * object2;

int main()
{
    
    // initialize objects
    object1 = new Object("eyeball.txt", "eyeball.bmp"); // declare here
    object2 = new Object("eyeball.txt", "eyeball1.bmp");

    object1->SetScale(0.70f, 0.70f, 0.70f);
    object2->SetScale(0.70f, 0.70f, 0.70f);
        
    object1->SetPosition(-PosX, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    object2->SetPosition(PosX, 0.0f, 0.0f);


    // render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
       // check if the object is in contact with the edge
       // play sound if edge collision detected
       if(object1->edgeDetected() == true)
        {
            // play some sound stream, looped
            engine->play2D("womp.wav");
        }

        if (object2->edgeDetected() == true)
        {
            // play some sound stream, looped
            engine->play2D("womp.wav");
        }

        // check for collision, if collided reset starting positions
        if (collisionDetected(*object1, *object2) == true)
        {
            object1->pos.x = -1.2f;
            object2->pos.x = 1.2f;
        }

        
    }


    return 0;
}


bool collisionDetected(Object a, Object b)
{
    GLfloat xdif = abs(a.pos.x - b.pos.x);
    GLfloat ydif = abs(a.pos.y - b.pos.y);

    xdif *= xdif;
    ydif *= ydif;

    GLfloat distance = sqrt( (a.pos.x - b.pos.x) + (a.pos.y - b.pos.y) );

    if( distance < sqrt( xdif + ydif ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Well Its of type float.. So the numbers I am thinking of is 1.01, 1.34, 2.06.. etc

Comment: Secondly: If the window borders are at `-2.126` and `1` (or vice versa for the other eyeball!?) your board is `3.126` units wide. But you consider the eyeballs to collide when they are less than `52` units apart? They would even collide when they were out of the axis if I understand your code corrrectly. You have too many magic numbers there.

Comment: To clarify my first comment and fix the typo: `eyeball1X < 1.0f && eyeball1X > 2.126f` 
tests if `eyeball1X` is less than 1 _and_ larger than 2.126.
How can any number be less than 1 and larger than 2.126 at the same time? This should be `||` instead of `&&` or you've mixed up some variable names.

Comment: thanks.. I adjusted to your suggestions.. 

I used the 3.126 units but I guess it will take more than that to get it working.

Comment: Every time you call `key_callback` all the `eyeball` variables get reset, should they use the data from object1/2 instead?

Comment: @Surt You were right.. I have updated the move function in Object.cpp to reflect the changes I made to support edge detection..

Comment: I have updated the main.cpp with a function collisionDetected(Object, Object)
if a collision is detected it will reset the eyeballs to their starting position..

but for some reason when it goes just a bit past each other they reset but not on contact. Can anyone see what I need to tweak..

Comment: `GLfloat distance = sqrt( (a.pos.x - b.pos.x) + (a.pos.y - b.pos.y) );`: what ??